# In DevExpress, how do I change the value of a cell after the value of another cell is change?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a DevExpress.XtraGrid.  I want the user to edit one of the columns and, after the edit is made, for the grid to update the value of another column.  I tried using the event CustomRowCellEdit, but it threw an error whenever I added that event; I wasn't sure how to change the value of another cell anyway.  Can someone explain how to do this?

So I've got a grid like this:

```
----------------
| A | B  | C   |
----------------
| 1 | 50 | 100 |
----------------
| 2 | 20 | 40  |
----------------
| 3 | 10 | 20  |
----------------
```

Let's say the user edits row 1, column B to be 25.  After they make the change, I want row 1, column C to be twice what B is.  So the end result is below where B1 is the value that is user entered and C1 is calculated based on the value in B1.

```
----------------
| A | B  | C   |
----------------
| 1 | 25 | 50  |
----------------
| 2 | 20 | 40  |
----------------
| 3 | 10 | 20  |
----------------
```

I tried this:

```
    private void myView_CustomRowCellEdit_1(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string newValue = e.CellValue.ToString();
        int index = myView.GetDataSourceRowIndex(e.RowHandle);
        myView.SetRowCellValue(index, "B", newValue);
    }
```

but I don't think the "B" referred to the column correctly and I got a run time error with a null reference exception.

Comment: Is the value in column C always twice the value from B? In that case you can use unbound expression.

Answer (score 0):

The [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event) event is intended to assign repository items to grid cells conditionally. For your case, it is necessary to handle the [GridView.CellValueChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CellValueChanged.event) event instead.

Refer to the [Modify and Validate Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Modify-and-Validate-Cell-Values) help topic for more information.